# kotlin SimpleDateFormat Unparseable date

Tags: kotlin

How to format date from `String` in kotlin?

I tried to parse it with a `SimpleDateFormat` but it always throws an Exception saying `Unparseable date: "21 Agt 2022"` when I try to parse the `String`.

This my code:

```kotlin
var spf = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy")
val newDate = spf.parse("21 Agt 2022")  // <- always error in this line
spf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val result = newDate?.let { it1 -> spf.format(it1) }.toString()
```

My app is running on API 21, so can't use a `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: Try `Aug`, not `Agt`?

Comment: is Agt maybe a non-English abbreviation for some month?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `java.time` and its `LocalDate`, you have two options so far:

- the [ThreeTen Android Backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP): a library that makes most `java.time` functionality available, you will have to import it
- [Android API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) available from Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0 or higher

### The reason for the error is the missing `Locale`, which would be a problem in `java.time` as well:

The abbreviation *Agt* for *August* is only used in two `Locale`s: Indonesia (where you seem to be from, at least judging from your profile page) and Kenia.

That means you can use your code, you just have to apply an Indonesian `Locale`:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // prepare the locale your input was created in
    val indonesia = Locale.forLanguageTag("id-ID")
    // use it in your SimpleDateFormat
    var spf = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", indonesia)
    // parse the value
    val newDate = spf.parse("21 Agt 2022")
    // print the value
    println(newDate)
}
```

Output:

```
Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 CEST 2022
```

This will create a `java.util.Date` which is in fact *more* than day of month, month of year and year… It has a time of day, too, but your input `String` does not contain any. That means it will *add* one, the start of day, most likely.

---

### Better / Newer / Date only: `java.time`

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // your input String
    val input = "21 Agt 2022"
    // prepare the locale your input uses
    val indonesia = Locale.forLanguageTag("id-ID")
    // prepare a DateTimeFormatter that considers Indonesian months
    val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM uuuu", indonesia)
    // parse the String using the DateTimeFormatter
    val localDate = LocalDate.parse(input, dtf)
    // print the result
    println(localDate)
}
```

Output:

```
2022-08-21
```